# Fatal error: require_once() using absolute path

Tags: php, absolute-path, require-once

I have the following file:

```
/home/public_html/grid.php
```

Inside it a require_once with absolute path that works:

```
require_once('/home/public_html/include/config.php');
```

So, why if I move this file to another directory,

```
/home/public_html/newfolder/grid.php
```

it stop working and returns a

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required './include/config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/public_html/include/config.php on line 2

Comment: Looks like too localized a question though

Answer (score 1):

Error message contradicts with what you say.

> Failed opening required './include/config.php'

It's relative path, not absolute

> in /home/public_html/include/config.php on line 2

why you're trying to include in config itself? you've said you're including from grid.php

Just use absolute path and where you really need it - everything would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can change default path by autoload, http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php